# Execute method when specific log appear

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

In an activity, i wish to trigger a specific method when a specific log appear.

Their is the log i want to detect :

> 11-17 15:35:41.626 8473-12293/com.planetvision.androidtv D/VLC:
>   [a12f67b4] **mpeg_audio decoder: emulated startcode (no startcode on
>   following frame)**

Comment: If you are the one writing the log message, add logic to your code at the point where you are logging it. Otherwise, unless you are on a rooted device, you do not have access to log messages from other apps.

Comment: I am not the one who is writing this log. It's VLC framework